# Wubi.exe doesn't install ubuntu on windows 7 64 bits

Tags: installation, wubi

Downloaded Wubi.exe to install Ubuntu on my Windows 7 64 bit OS. While running, I selected a space of 50 GB on my D:drive to install ubuntu. 
But after downloading, it showed an error, "image file not found" and Ubuntu wasn't installed.

Comment: What does the log file say? You can find it in the `%temp%` directory named `wubi-nn.nn-revnnn.log` (where n's are numeric e.g. `wubi-12.04.2-rev273.log`)? You can [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) the contents, edit your question with the link, and comment back here when done. Thanks

Comment: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5879871/), the link of the pastebin.@bcbc

Answer (score 1):

You're running version 266 of `wubi.exe` - the original 12.04 version.

This will not work anymore. You need the one for 12.04.2 (version 273). You can get it here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Answer (score 0):

Download Wubi installer from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) and Ubuntu 12.04.2 iso file from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
Place both file in same folder and run wubi installer.

Comment: thanks, does it have a option to locate the iso?